# HTTPS in Undertow

Tags: servlets, ssl, https, undertow

I have a web service that runs on Tomcat and decided to try using Undertow instead. Generally, it's quite good, but I need HTTPS support and cannot enable it. Here is some helloworld code:

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = deployment()
            .setClassLoader(ServletServer.class.getClassLoader())
            .setContextPath("/")
            .setDeploymentName("AuthenticationService.war")
            .addServlet(servlet("WSServlet", WSServlet.class))
            .addListener(listener(WSServletContextListener.class))
            .setResourceManager(new FileResourceManager(new File("src/main/webapp"), 100));

    DeploymentManager manager = defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
    manager.deploy();

    HttpHandler servletHandler = manager.start();

    SSLContext context = createSSLContext(loadKeyStore("server-keystore.jsk"), loadKeyStore("server-truststore.jks"));
    PathHandler path = Handlers.path(servletHandler);

    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
            .addHttpsListener(8443, "localhost", context)
            .setHandler(path)
            .build();
    server.start();
```

And the createSSLContext method:

```
private static SSLContext createSSLContext(final KeyStore keyStore, final KeyStore trustStore) throws Exception {
    KeyManager[] keyManagers;
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, /* password */);
    keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

    TrustManager[] trustManagers;
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
    trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

    SSLContext sslContext;
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

    return sslContext;
}
```

And loadKeyStore method:

```
private static KeyStore loadKeyStore(String name) throws Exception {
    final InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(name);

    try(InputStream is = stream) {
        KeyStore loadedKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        loadedKeystore.load(is, /* password */);
        return loadedKeystore;
    }
}
```

The server is starting, but trying to send requests to https://localhost:8443/... has no effect, no logs or exceptions or some reaction. When using http://localhost:8443 it throws exception

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I am new to all web technologies, so all that may be strange. So what's wrong here?

Comment: Does this same deployment work with a HTTP listener?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

I have it working.  First generate your keys if you've not done so already:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

KEYSTORE=my-keystore.jks
TRUSTSTORE=my-truststore.ts
CERT=my-client.cer

rm $KEYSTORE
rm $CERT
rm $TRUSTSTORE

# these passwords must be copied to the private config file(s)
KEYSTORE_STOREPASS=password1
KEYSTORE_KEYPASS=password2
TRUSTSTORE_STOREPASS=password3

keytool -genkey -alias pomochatserver \
    -keyalg RSA -keystore $KEYSTORE \
    -dname "cn=localhost, ou=IT, o=Continuent, c=US" \
    -storepass $KEYSTORE_STOREPASS -keypass $KEYSTORE_KEYPASS

# enter the *KEYSTORE_STOREPASS* when prompted
keytool -export -alias pomochatserver -file $CERT -keystore $KEYSTORE

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias pomochatserver -file $CERT \
    -keystore $TRUSTSTORE -storepass $TRUSTSTORE_STOREPASS -noprompt
```

... then in your java code:

```
public static SSLContext serverSslContext(String password1, String password2, String password3) {
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = loadKeyStore("my-keystore.jks", password1);
        KeyStore trustStore = loadKeyStore("my-truststore.ts", password3);
        return createSSLContext(keyStore, trustStore, password2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static SSLContext createSSLContext(final KeyStore keyStore, final KeyStore trustStore, String keyStorePassword) throws IOException {
    try {
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Unable to create and initialise the SSLContext", e);
    }
}

private static KeyStore loadKeyStore(final String name, String password) throws IOException {
    try(InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(name)) {
        KeyStore loadedKeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        loadedKeystore.load(stream, password.toCharArray());
        return loadedKeystore;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException(String.format("Unable to load KeyStore %s", name), e);
    }
}
```

and finally to create the server

```
        Undertow webAppServer = Undertow.builder()
                .addHttpsListener(
                        port,
                        hostname,
                        serverSslContext(password1, password2, password3)
                )
                .setHandler(handlers, manager.start()))
                .build();
```

Comment: @promo I have modified the code as per what you gave here and it is exactly identical with my code and certificate creation process. Still facing an error as `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown` also another xino error `UT005013: An IOException occurred`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but the self-signed and/or not trusted certificates would cause the issue, but you are supposed to get some exception asbout this

I don't know know what is `undertow`, but you may check the `SSL` configs from the doc.

You also need to check if both the server and client supports common cipher(s) and protocol(s)
For instance default package of JRE does not support `AES_256`.